# How to access all the child table entries based on parent table entry in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, html, flask, sqlalchemy

I am developing a flask-based website, I have two tables in the database, `Customer(PK=sno, ...)` and `Item(PK=iid, ..., FK=customer.sno)`.
I want to display all the Items corresponding to any customer at a time when I click **Bill** button corresponding to the customer.

File `app.py` contains code

```
@app.route("/show_bill/<int:sno>")
def show_bill(sno):
    customer = Customer.query.filter_by(sno=sno).first()
    show_bill = Item.query.filter_by(cid=sno)
    return render_template('show_bill.html', customer=customer, show_bill=show_bill)
```

And, `show_bill.html` contains

```
<div class="container my-3">
    <h2>Bill for customer {{ customer.cname }}</h2>
        {% if show_bill|length == 0 %}
            <div class="alert alert-dark" role="alert">
                No Item found. Add first Item now to appear for this customesr!
            </div>
        {% else %} 
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th scope="col">SNo</th>
                    <th scope="col">Customer ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name of Item</th>
                    <th scope="col">No. of Items</th>
                    <th scope="col">Rate</th>
                    <th scope="col">Discount(%)</th>
                    <th scope="col">Time</th>
                    <th scope="col">Actions(Edit)</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                        
                <tbody>
                {% for item in show_bill %}
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">{{loop.index}}</th>
                    <td>{{item.cid}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.iname}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.icount}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.irate}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.idiscount}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.date_created}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/update_item/{{item.iid}}" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm mx-1">Update</button>
                        <a href="/delete_item/{{item.iid}}" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm mx-1">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        {% endif %}
</div>
```

But, on clicking **Bill** button, I get an error:
`TypeError: object of type 'BaseQuery' has no len()`
Also if I remove `show_bill=show_bill`, It renders to show_bill.html page but do not show data as we are not fetching any (Probably the problem is here).
Can someone help to resolve this? Or any alternative way to get the same thing.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `.all()` query to return a list of all the desired items in your table, like this:

```py
show_bill = Item.query.filter_by(cid=sno).all()
```

Without this part, SQL returns your query as an object instead of an iterable list.